# VeeValidate - how to validate URL that should be with http://

Tags: vuejs2, vee-validate

I have tried to validate my input with:

```
<input 
     type="text"
     name="webhookURL"
     placeholder="Enter webhook URL"
     class="text-input"
     v-validate="'required|url'"
/>
```

but it's returns true if I will fill the input like this: google.com,
so I need that validation return true if I will fill like this http://exampleURL.com (with http:// or https://)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use the `require_protocol`

```
<input v-validate="{url: {require_protocol: true }}"
```

See the [doc](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/guide/rules.html#url)